# How do I calculate the (moving) axis of rotation of a rigid body once a force was applied?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm trying to program a Space-Simulation-Game and am for now just trying to grasp the physics I will be dealing with before coding anything.

Currently I consider the easiest scenario. A box-shaped, homogeneous spaceship in empty space with no external forces acting upon it. Now I mount an engine on the surface of that box. The engine has no mass  itself, is at the position $ \vec r$ relative to the boxes center of mass and has an orientation of $ \vec v$ (meaning that it does not have to be normal to the surface). For further simplcity the engine also fires just once and instantaneously; transmitting its complete momentum in an instant (like an idealized rifle).

So if $\vec v = \lambda * \vec r$, there is no rotation, just translation. This way I could say to my program something like: $\vec r_{Spaceship}(t)=\vec v*t + C_1$
$\vec \omega_{Spaceship}(t)= 0$

But with the other cases I have my problems. For example:

If $\vec v * \vec r = 0$, then there is no translation; just pure rotation. Now I know a thing or two about principal moments of inertia and the intermediate axis theorem but what I would like is a complete (and analytical) solution for $\vec \omega(t)$ or at least a set of equations of motion which the game can then simply interate over.

PS: I assume that the case where there is a mix of rotation and translation is then solved by superimposing the rotation with the translation. Calculated from a parallel and orthoganl part of $\vec v$ with respect to the position vector $\vec r$.

[image]

Comment: Read Lecture notes I, and II for [Rigid Body Dynamics](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simulation because there is no analytical solution for $\boldsymbol{\omega}(t)$ for the general case.

Use the equations of motion for a free rigid body to find how the motion changes at each time step.

The easiest way to handle this is to track momentum and angular momentum instead of velocity and angular velocity. See [Physically Based Modeling - Lecture I](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf) for free motion modeling equations and structures.

For each body you need to know their mass $m$ and the three principal moments of inertia $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_3$. In fact as you will see later, it is the inverse of these three you need.

Here is an overview of the simulation steps:

1. At each step you know the position vector of the center of mass $\boldsymbol{r}_C$, the orientation of the body using a 3×3 rotation matrix $\mathrm{R}$ or a quaternion $\boldsymbol{q}$, the momentum of the body $\boldsymbol{p}$ and the angular momentum at the center of mass $\boldsymbol{L}_C$.

   These are typically condenced into a single 3+4+3+3=13 element vector, called the state vector $$ \boldsymbol{Y} = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{r}_C \\ \boldsymbol{q} \\ \boldsymbol{p} \\ \boldsymbol{L}_C }$$

   If the quaternion is used, the rotation matrix needs to be extracted from the quaternion  $$ \mathrm{R} = {\rm rot}(\boldsymbol{q}) $$ Look up quaternion to rotation matrix, or use the standard formula $$ \mathrm{R} = \mathbf{1} + 2 w [\boldsymbol{z}\times] + 2 [ \boldsymbol{z}\times] [\boldsymbol{z}\times] $$ where ${\bf 1}$ is the identity matrix, and $[\boldsymbol{z}\times]$ is the 3×3 [skew symmetric cross product operator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Cross_product) of the vector part of the quaternion $\boldsymbol{q} = (\boldsymbol{z},w)$.
2. Evaluate the inverse inertia tensor in the inertial frame basis vectors

   $$ {\bf I}^{-1} = {\rm R} \begin{bmatrix} I_1^{-1} & & \\ & I_2^{-1} & \\ & & I_2^{-1} \end{bmatrix} {\rm R}^\intercal $$
3. Evaluate the motion of the rigid body from the momentum vectors.

   $$ \begin{aligned} \boldsymbol{v}_C &= \tfrac{1}{m} \boldsymbol{p} \\
   \boldsymbol{\omega} &= {\bf I}^{-1} \boldsymbol{L}_C \end{aligned} $$

   where $\boldsymbol{v}_C$ is the velocity of the center of mass, and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the angular velocity vector.

   Note that the position and quaternion values have the following time derivatives

   $$ \begin{aligned} \boldsymbol{\dot{r}}_C & = \boldsymbol{v}_C \\
    \boldsymbol{\dot{q}} &= \tfrac{1}{2} (\boldsymbol{\omega}) \boldsymbol{q} \end{aligned}$$ where $(\boldsymbol{\omega})$ is the angular velocity vector converted into the quaternion $(\boldsymbol{\omega},0)$ before the quaternion product is evaluated.
4. Evaluate the net force $\boldsymbol{F}$ and net torque about the center of mass $\boldsymbol{\tau}_C$ for the time step given the position and motion of the body.

   Note that the equations of motion in terms if momentum are $$ \begin{aligned} \boldsymbol{F} &= \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{p} \\ \boldsymbol{\tau}_C &= \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{L}_C \end{aligned}$$
5. Evaluate the rate of change of each part of the state vector

   $$\boldsymbol{\dot{Y}} = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v}_C \\ \tfrac{1}{2} (\boldsymbol{\omega}) \boldsymbol{q} \\ \boldsymbol{F} \\ \boldsymbol{\tau}_C } $$
6. Combine the above into a single function $$\boldsymbol{\dot{Y}} = f( t,\,\boldsymbol{Y})$$ which you feed into a numerical integrator to advance the state vector over time.

   Care must be taken after each simulation step to re-normalize the quaternion $\boldsymbol{q}$ such that $ \|\boldsymbol{z} \|^2 + w^2 = 1$

   Additionally, each simulation step should be short enough where the orientation of the body does not change more than a few degrees, otherwise the results would accumulate a lot of error.

---

As a side note, if you know the motion of the center of mass, located at $\boldsymbol{r}_C$ and moving with $\boldsymbol{v}_C$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ then you can find where the instant axis of rotation is.

- Direction of the axis is parallel to $\boldsymbol{\omega}$
- Point on the axis closest to the body center is $$ \boldsymbol{r}_{\rm rot} = \boldsymbol{r}_C + \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{v}_C}{ \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \|^2 }$$
- Parallel velocity along the axis is $$ \boldsymbol{v}_{\rm rot} = \boldsymbol{v}_C + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times ( \boldsymbol{r}_{\rm rot} - \boldsymbol{r}_C) = \left( \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_C} {\| \boldsymbol{\omega}\|^2} \right) \boldsymbol{\omega}$$

Comment: Look at [this C# implementation](https://github.com/ja72/FortranMbdVector/blob/e5784a6830e74e134552f7f05c75bc6983882a93/CSharp/Dynamics/RigidBody.cs#L120) that tracks any point (not the center of mass) and is slightly more general variation of the above procedure. Also [the Fortran](https://github.com/ja72/FortranMbdVector/blob/e5784a6830e74e134552f7f05c75bc6983882a93/Fortran/Source/mod_vectors_rigid_body.f90#L170) version of the same procedure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful and comprehensive answer!
I'm now trying to calculate some cases by hand to sort out my wrong assumptions; so ofc some more detailed questions popped up. Most importantly concerning the state vector and its derivative as given in the Lecture notes I (unconstrained  motion) chapter 2.11 "Rigid Body Equations of Motion".

As far as I understand: Y itself, x, P and L are vectors, while R is the rotation matrix, right?

Then d/dt of Y, v, F and tau should also be vectors. What confuses me is "omega(t) "star" R(t)". It should be a matrix, but how?

Comment: Nevermind; I found the answer. omega* is the matrix corresponding to omega which allows to do the cross-product as a matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get pure rotation from a single engine. If the engine does not point into the center of mass, the resulting movement will be a mix of angular and normal velocities.

During the impulse with a force, the same force with opposite direction will be a reaction in the center of mass. This force couple will in general cause some angular velocity and the rest of the energy will go into normal velocity in direction of the impulse force.